# KnockoutJS + Polymer: bindings break (Outside of Chrome)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, cross-browser, polymer

EDIT: This only appears outside of Chrome

I'm using KO to fill in elements using foreach bindings. On the other side of the coin, I've got Polymer loaded up to make use of Google's Material Design styling.

The issue is that there seems to be an assertion in the platform.js file (Polymer) that is trying to take over the `data-bind` even though Polymer doesn't use the data-bind attribute.

Wondering if anybody has had any experience using both of these, or any suggestions? Error is below:

`Error: Unable to process binding "template: function (){return { foreach:sessions} }"
Message: Assertion failed`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rmp6c/3/

EDIT: So I've setup the debug version, and it appears that inside ShadowDOM/src/wrappers.js on line 31 there is an `assert(b)` function that is being passed a boolean. This is called 100s of times by a Node.js file, and to fix this looks like it would require a fairly large rewrite.

My fix for this has been to use jQuery to insert the DOM element with the foreach binding, and then apply my KO bindings inside a `$(document).ready(function() {});` tag. This appears to work on all browsers.

Comment: Can you post some more context? This is the whole message, don't you have a stackstracte where is the error coming? How do you use polymer? Can you maybe create a jsfiddle with your current setup?

Comment: Polymer is minified - so it simply says line 12.

The only setup needed is Polymer with a Knockout foreach. I'll post a jsfiddle shortly

Comment: I don't see any error in your fiddle, it is working completly fine...

Comment: Are you using Firefox?

Comment: Include the non-minified/debug version :-) EDIT: or include the polymer.js.map file to ease debugging. I believe that is a [source map](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/).

Comment: bit off topic, but knockout released their own custom components.  We tried both polymer and knockout custom components and prefer the latter for its simplicity.  Check out this demo, it's fun to watch: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2014/06/11/architecting-large-single-page-applications-with-knockout-js/

Comment: also - that's a nasty fix you had to do :)  I'd suggest answering your own question and marking it accepted so it gets out of the "unanswered" queue

Comment: @Milimetric - Yeah - I know, but it's working :) Thanks for the reminder - I'll do that now (Totally forgot about this question) - Also, I attended a talk by Steve where he presented that talk live :) It was indeed a good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fix for this has been to use jQuery to insert the DOM element with the foreach binding, and then apply my KO bindings inside a $(document).ready(function() {}); tag. This appears to work on all browsers.

While this isn't a great fix - it is the only one that has worked properly. I've reached out to Steve Sanderson of KnockoutJS and believe he's looking into it. The reason that I went with this fix over just using Knockout Custom components, is that the Polymer components offer Material Design as per Google's new design specs, and the web front-end that I'm building is intrinsically tied to my company's mobile application, so I wanted to maintain a cohesive design.

Comment: Sure - it's just:
$(document).ready(function() { ko.applyBindings(new knockoutModel(), document.getElementById('elementID')); });

Answer (score 3):

If anyone has this issue, it is because you are using the `ko.applyBindings(viewModel)` method, and in here knockout uses `window.document.body` to get the node, which in turn misses the shadowDOM polyfill which webcomponents.js uses.

To get around this, you have two options, use the second overload of the apply bindings method - you'll probably get a successfully wrapped node this way.

Alternatively, you can load this shim immediately after the knockout declaration (some boilerplate borrowed from knockout.validation:

```
(function (factory) {
    // Module systems magic dance.

    if (typeof require === "function" && typeof module === "object") {
        // CommonJS or Node: hard-coded dependency on "knockout"
        factory(require("knockout"));
    } else if (typeof define === "function" && define["amd"]) {
        // AMD anonymous module with hard-coded dependency on "knockout"
        define(["knockout"], factory);
    } else {
        // <script> tag: use the global `ko` object, attaching a `mapping` property
        factory(ko);
    }
}(function (ko) {

    if (typeof (ko) === undefined) { throw 'Knockout is required, please ensure it is loaded before loading this shim'; }

    if (WebComponents && WebComponents.flags.shadow && ShadowDOMPolyfill) {

        var _originalApplyBindings = ko.applyBindings;

        ko.applyBindings = function (viewModel, rootNode) {
            if (rootNode) {
                rootNode = ShadowDOMPolyfill.wrapIfNeeded(rootNode);
            } else {
                rootNode = ShadowDOMPolyfill.wrapIfNeeded(window.document.body);
            }
            _originalApplyBindings(viewModel, rootNode);
        }
    }
}));
```

Hopefully this helps anyone with the same issue.