# Using both Knockout.js and Polymer causes an error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, polymer

Hey I'm trying to use both polymer and knockout.js in one Html document, when I was only using knockout.js everything works fine,but as soon as I include the "platform.js" from polymer I recive the following errror message (only for Internet Explorer),

> Assertion failed

which is caused when the data-binding is applyed:

```
ko.applyBindings(new ActualActionsViewModel);
```

Has someone experienced the same problem and ah a solution for me?

Comment: Just a notice - I guess it should be `ko.applyBindings(new ActualActionsViewModel());`, you're creating an instance of view model.

Comment: Of course the brackets shouldn't be missing

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780854/knockoutjs-polymer-bindings-break-outside-of-chrome

Comment: No I've already seen this before I posted this question

Comment: I posted an answer to this on the question @DianaNassar linked.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues with KO and Polymer. In my case, `foreach:` binds with KO get usurped by Polymer. My solution was to inject my View into the DOM with `$(document).on('ready')`. This worked as Polymer runs through and does its initial binds with platform.js before the KO data is injected.